# Dynamically change TextView android

Tags: android, textview

Is there a way to change TextView Dynamically.
I have SharedPreferences and it is OK in the "GameScreen". But also i want to show users score
in "First Scree"(not gamescreen) .
THE problem is that it changes only if i close-open application

```
mGameSettings = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        TextView goldmenu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.goldmenu);
        goldmenu.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gold_color));
        int curScore = mGameSettings.getInt(GAME_PREFERENCES_SCORE, 0);
        String mmGold = String.valueOf(curScore);  
        goldmenu.setText(mmGold);
```

(Edited)

Comment: please be more specific and provide some details as to what you dont know how to do on a textView

Comment: Why are you using the shared preferences at all! its for permenant data... If you are trying to read a value in different activities use lets say static class constants... Be more specific, give some details, show some code....

Comment: i think you should learn about how to switch between activities and send data between them. See this tutorial , it may be useful for you : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/117/how-to-switch-between-different-activities-in-android/

Comment: My bad , guys. Forgot about onResume() method

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you need to do is find the view given it's resource id. The resource id is set in your xml via the id tag, something like,

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/text_id"
     ....
     .... />
```

Within your activity, you can access the TextView in the layout via it's resource

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id."text_id");
```

and then set your text by

```
text.setText("text string");
```

You can also change view and layout parameters

```
text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
text.setTextSize(12);
//etc.
```

or

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
//etc.
text.setLayoutParams(params);
```